# Issue with Facebook API / Timeline

Tags: php, facebook, web, facebook-timeline

Ever since *Timeline* was added to Facebook the photos have been showing up on my website. This isn't ideal because there are a lot of duplicates and also the latest gallery doesn't show up because the timeline takes first position.

Here is my code. I am hoping there is some type of "if" command I can give to keep the gallery timeline from showing up.

```
$show=1;

if($show)
{



if(!$_GET[hash])

    $la = getLastFacebookAlbum();

else $la = getFacebookAlbum($_GET[hash]);



if(!$_GET[image]) { $image=getFacebookAlbumFirst($la[aid]); $iid=getFacebookAlbumFirstId($la[aid]); $current=1; } else {$image=getFacebookSkippedImage($la[aid],$_GET[image]); $iid=getFacebookSkippedImageId($la[aid],$_GET[image]); $current=$_GET[image]+1;}



$total = getFacebookAlbumCount($la[aid]);



    $ownlink=urlencode($server."photos.php?hash=".$la[aid]);

    $info=@getimagesize($image);
    if(!$info[0]) $info[0]=2;

    if($info[0]>$info[1]) $isze='width="471" height="331"'; else {

        $koef=ceil($info[1]/$info[0]);

        $expected_width=ceil(331/$koef);

        $margin=(471/2)-(ceil($expected_width/2))-10;

        $isze='height="331" style="margin-left:'.$margin.'px;"';

    }

}
```